# Google Charts won't display when using php and sql

Tags: php, mysql, google-visualization

I'm creating a simple chart using Google Charts. I am using PHP and MYSQL when executing data. I was searching for answers and tried but it does not display the chart

Here is my **test.php** file

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
      // Define the chart to be drawn.
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Specialization', 'Facultyno'],
        <?php
        require_once('../mydb_connect.php');
        $query="SELECT distinct(s.specializationname) as 'specialization', count(fs.facultyid) as 'facultyno' from thesisdb.specialization s join facultyspecialization fs on s.specializationid=fs.specializationid group by s.specializationID;";

        $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

        echo "['".$row['specialization']."',".$row['facultyno']."],";
        } 
        ?>

        ]);
        var options = {'title':'Number of Faculty Specializations',
                       'width':1300,
                       'height':900};

      }
      // Instantiate and draw the chart.
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('no_of_specialization'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="no_of_specialization"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

When looking for the problem, I was testing if the data can be executed and It worked

here is the php code

```
<?php
        require_once('../mydb_connect.php');
        $query="SELECT distinct(s.specializationname) as specialization, count(fs.facultyid) as facultyno from thesisdb.specialization s join facultyspecialization fs on s.specializationid=fs.specializationid group by s.specializationID;";

        $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                          {  
                               echo "{$row['specialization']}";
                               echo " - ";
                               echo "{$row['facultyno']}<br>";  
                          } 
        ?>
```

This is the data that should be displayed on Google Charts

Artificial Intelligence - 1

Biocomputation - 3

Computer and Network Security - 2

Human-Computer Interaction - 3

Information Management and Analytics - 1

Mobile and Internet Computing - 1

Real-World Computing - 1

Software Theory - 2

Theoretical Computer Science - 1

I need your help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every thing is ok in your code. but you are using one extra curely braces "}". remove the extra curely braces '}' after this code.

```
var options = {'title':'Number of Faculty Specializations',
                       'width':1300,
                       'height':900};
```

if you faced problem to finding the extra curely braces "}". just copy and paste below code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
            // Define the chart to be drawn.
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Specialization', 'Facultyno'],
                <?php
                require_once('../mydb_connect.php');
                $query="SELECT distinct(s.specializationname) as 'specialization', count(fs.facultyid) as 'facultyno' from thesisdb.specialization s join facultyspecialization fs on s.specializationid=fs.specializationid group by s.specializationID;";

                $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                    echo "['".$row['specialization']."',".$row['facultyno']."],";
                }
                ?>

            ]);
            var options = {'title':'Number of Faculty Specializations',
                'width':1300,
                'height':900};

        // Instantiate and draw the chart.
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('no_of_specialization'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="no_of_specialization"/>
</body>
</html>
```